# Can't get user_id in database after Ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In javascript I do an ajax call to the create function of deliveries_controller. This puts a new Delivery in the database with a product and quantity. I also try to put the current_user as user_id in the database, but for some reason it stays nil in the database.

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/deliveries",
  data: { delivery: {ingredient: "meel", quantity: "800", scenario_id: "3"} },
  success: function(){
    alert('Success!');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('No success');
  }
});
```

I just pass some dummy data to test it all out.

and my deliveries_controller:

```
class DeliveriesController < ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery

  def index
    @storages = Storage.where(user_id: current_user)
  end


  def addQuantity
   @storage = Storage.where(user_id: current_user.id)
   @storage.update_all ("quantity = (quantity+200)")
   redirect_to deliveries_url
  end

  def create

    @delivery = Delivery.new(delivery_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @delivery.save
      format.html do
        render :nothing => true
      end
      format.json { render json: @delivery.to_json }
    else
      format.html { render :nothing => true} ## Specify the format in which you are rendering "new" page
      format.json { render json: @delivery.errors } ## You might want to specify a json format as well
    end

  end

end

private

  def delivery_params
      params.require(:delivery).permit(:user_id, :ingredient, :quantity, :scenario_id)
  end

end
```

New entries are created in the database, but whichever way I try to pass the user_id as param it isn't saved in the database.

I tried it like:
`@delivery = Delivery.new(delivery_params, :user_id => current_user)`,

```
@user_id = current_user
@delivery = Delivery.new(delivery_params, @user_id)
```

and

`params.require(:delivery).permit(:user_id, :ingredient, :quantity, :scenario_id).merge(user_id: current_user)`

log:
`Started POST "/deliveries" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-03 12:59:37 +0100
Processing by DeliveriesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"delivery"=>{"ingredient"=>"meel", "quantity"=>"800", "scenario_id"=>"3"}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709' LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "deliveries" ("created_at", "ingredient", "quantity", "scenario_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-11-03 11:59:37.253274"], ["ingredient", "meel"], ["quantity", 800], ["scenario_id", 3], ["updated_at", "2014-11-03 11:59:37.253274"]]
   (12.5ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 13.1ms)`

but the user_id for Delivery stays nil. How would I pass the user_id from the current_user so it's saved in the database with the json I retrieve from the ajax call?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I fixed it the following way:
I send json data to javascript with content_tag:
`= content_tag(:div,"", id: "storages", data:{url: Storage.where(user_id: current_user)})`
this data is handled, and the user_id is suddenly accepted :)

thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you post your Delivery model source code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
@delivery = current_user.deliveries.new(delivery_params)
```

Comment: I have tried `@delivery = @user.Delivery.new(delivery_params)` or something like that, but still the same problem. When I try your piece of code it throws undefined class deliveries (tried changing it to Delivery and delivery, Deliveries but all the same).

Comment: Its not `@user.Delivery.new(delivery_params)`, use `@user.deliveries.new(delivery_params)`

Comment: Tried @user.deliveries.new(delivery_params) too already, didn't work. But somehow I fixed it by just sending data to javascript with content_tag, see my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
@delivery = Delivery.new(delivery_params.merge(user: current_user))
```

OR

```
@delivery = Delivery.new(delivery_params)
@delivery.user =  current_user
```

Comment: Tried both ways already but it won't put anything in the database. It doesn't even show the user_id as params in the log. I have updated the first post with the log output when a new Delivery is put in the database.

Answer (score -1):

Put current user_id on hidden field on HTML and send it with ajax like other params

Comment: This is really bad way of solving this problem. Yes it would probably work, but it could be really big security issue if you could create delivery to any user in the database by change of hidden field value.

Comment: Somehow I fixed it by just sending data to javascript with content_tag, see my edited post.